# Does iTunes Sound Check Lower Sound Quality?

Tags: macos, iphone, itunes, sound-volume

I have found that many do not like the Sound Check feature in iTunes.

Will enabling Sound Check lower sound quality?

Why does/does it not reduce sound quality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not bad to have sound check enabled in iTunes.

Having it enabled does not make the sound quality of songs worse.

Sound Check works simply by dynamically raising or lowering the playback volume, just as you yourself can raise and lower the playback volume in iTunes without affecting sound quality.

iTunes raises/lowers playback volume according to the audio normalisation ID3-tag within the audio file. These tags are created automatically when you rip a CD with iTunes, and automatically added when you import files lackings these tags into iTunes.

The normalisation tag simply tells what the average volume of the song is. Note that iTunes recognizes albums, so that when playing back and album, it will adjust according to the average track volume of the album as a whole, instead of changing the playback volume for each song individually. Therefore your album listening experience is not harmed.

iTunes automatically ensures that the volume is not raised so high that neither clipping occurs or compression effects are introduced. Therefore your sound quality is not harmed.

All in all this means that enabling Sound Check is safe, does not change the audio content of your songs, thus not reducing their quality. It simply change the playback volume slightly so that you get an pleasurable listening experience without having to tweak your playback volume every time you select a new album.

Comment: When you enable sound check on and iDevice, does it do the exact same thing as I would do in iTunes on the Mac? Even the part about if you were only the play an album, it would adjust to the whole album and not every song that you have on your device?

Comment: Note that whilst this answer is basically correct, the explanation of how it works is in error. There is no normalisation or compression applied, it is done using a 'last before the output' volume control called [ReplayGain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReplayGain)

Comment: @Tetsujin This is exactly how I wrote that it works - iTunes ensures that no compression occurs, and the audio content is unchanged. The name of the tag is "normalisation", so even though no normalisation is applied to the audio content, the tag is still called that.

Comment: "ensures that no compression occurs" is simply an incorrect statement. If you increase the signal on digital audio far enough you do not get compression, you get clipping. Secondly, changing the volume even at the last stage before converting to analog *always* introduces change, however minimal [this would not be noticeable by anything other than a direct digital comparison so can be considered irrelevant] [cont'd...]

Comment: [cont'd...] Thirdly, whatever the tag is called, normalisation is not an average volume, it is a peak measurement. Almost all commercial audio has already been 'normalised' [if not also then re-balanced at album level]

Comment: Yes, but the "normalisation" that happens to commercial audio is very much different from what Sound Check does. I'm writing average volume because this is how Apple describes what their feature does. They do not list is as the peak measurement. In reality this is ofcourse a simplification - in reality the normalisation tag is neither the average volume nor the peak measurement, but a combination of multiple things including for example the peak measurement. However, iTunes specifically does not use the peak measurement information in the ID3 tag for its Sound Check feature.

Comment: Why is it an incorrect statement that iTunes ensures that no compression occurs? - It ensures that no clipping takes place by pushing the volume up too high - but are you arguing that changing the playback volume (without taking it up too high or down too low) creates a compression effect? Doesn't make sense?

Comment: I already explained the normalisation process in my first comment - read up on [ReplayGain](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=ReplayGain) It's not important that any given app uses that exact algorithm, the end result is similar. It's an RMS process, not peak. & The reason that the word "compression" is incorrect is that digital audio [again as already explained] does not compress with volume [unless done expressly]. Only analog can do that. [cont'd...]

Comment: [cont'd...] Digital will clip, badly, without some kind of brick-wall limiter in the chain [potentially at hardware level these days to prevent amateurs from damaging their systems by miscomprehension of how the gain-staging works]

Comment: I still do not think that you're correct. iTunes specifically ensures that it does not raise the volume so high that clipping encurs. Also it does not do compression nor uses the "ReplayGain" technique that you link. Therefore sound quality is not worsened with iTunes Sound Check.

Comment: You are badly missing the point. You're agreeing with me now, but still haven't got it. To a sound engineer, your misinterpretation is akin to not knowing which is upload & which is download.

Comment: Could you then explain to me what I'm misinterpreting or where I am wrong? (I know some signal theory) I'm trying to state very clearly that iTunes does NOT do compression - as this is the very common misunderstanding that led people to say that Sound Check is "bad".

Comment: "iTunes automatically ensures that the volume is not raised so high that compression effects occurs. " This is basically wrong. Compression will not occur, at any volume, clipping will occur. Limiting might be strapped across the outputs, but that is not iTunes, it's a hardware protection. I've explained all this several times.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you're getting at. The programmer(s) behind iTunes decides what happens. They can decide that the volume can be raised so high that clipping will occur - which is a terrible idea. They could also decide that compression should occur (i.e. they put in compression functionality) - this is what many thought has happened. Therefore I'm writing that compression does not occur. The programmers have decided to make the program such that compression does not occur, not does clipping occur. I hope you see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing distortion on both headphones and via airplay (when playing music from my iPhone). When investigating, I discovered that sound check was on. I turned it off and the distortion went away. The tracks where I noticed this were:

Field of Dreams, opening credits (track 1).
Star Trek V, opening credits (track 1).

Note: Both albums were ripped from CD using iTunes, 256 kbps AAC and played via iTunes Match.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I hate this option, by default it was on and I was thinking why audio quality is that poor, after while I found that option and after I turned it off I have a better life since then!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions. To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).   - From Review